# Trigonometry in Population

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

I was trying to find a function that would follow this model:
[image]

The Y axis is population; the x axis is years. Each point is a local max or min point.
Is it possible? I have no idea how to make a sinusoidal wave that decreases over time..
I need a clear formula that will be able to help me predict populations in 62 years and in 117 years.

Comment: There can be infinite curves passing through these points - not just the Sine curve. You can use techniques in Numerical Analysis like Lagrange's technique, Newtonian Techniques to have a curve which passes through these points

Comment: Do you intend for those points to be the local max and mins?

Comment: @VHP but there has to be one specific curve where each of these points is a maximum or a minimum

Comment: @SammyBlack yes, I do intend for those points to be the local max and mins

Comment: A useful way to introduce decay is to multiply by a decreasing function, e.g. $e^{-x}$ or $\frac 1 x$.

Comment: The points seem to lie on two separate lines.  If you can parametrize those lines, then you can squeeze a sinusoid between them (until they cross!).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that the upper envelope curve (the line with negative slope passing through your upper points) is given by $y = u(x)$ and the lower envelope is given by $y = \ell(x)$.

The midline curve for your sinusoid will be given by their average
$$
m(x) = \frac{u(x) + \ell(x)}{2},
$$
and their amplitude is given by
$$
a(x) = \frac{u(x) - \ell(x)}{2}.
$$
Notice that $m + a = u$ and $m - a = \ell$, as functions.

Now, your function is
$$
f(x) = m(x) + a(x) \cdot \cos( \omega x ),
$$
where $\frac{2 \pi}{\omega}$ is the period.  I have ignored phase shift, as you seem interested in a wave that achieves its maximum at $x = 0$.